# Pass id of selected row to Component tag inside blade file

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to pass id of currently selected row inside for loop when someone clicks on it

And pass that id to vue component

My index.blade file

```
@foreach($cats as $cat)
<tr>
<td class="catme" data-id="{{$cat->id}}">{{$cat-> title}}</td></tr>
@endforeach



<car-component i want to pass prop  here></car-component>


<script>
$('.catme').on('click',function(){
var a = $('.catme').attr('data-id')


})

</script>
```

I am unable to set that a varaiable value to that component

```
                  <----- GOAL ----->
```

My requirements is to have a component inside a blade file and to have forloop with multiple records such that if one row is selected its id is passed as prop to the component but it is outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below function and it should work

```
<script>
$('.catme').on('click',function(){
    var a = $(this).data('id')
    this.$refs.component.prop = a;
});

</script>
```

Comment: ok i am going to try but i want to ask i have many components so how it will detect my car component
I mean kindly explain it a little bit what your solution suggests

Comment: if you are not able to add the attribute with above code try this code

``document.querySelector('car-component').setAttribute("class", "democlass");``

Comment: You should try to use Vue code instead of Vanilla Javascript, and handle the click event from there..

Comment: My requirements is to have a component inside a blade file and to have forloop with multiple records such that if one row is selected its id is passed as prop to the component but it is outside the loop

Comment: Yes.. that ok.. you can still write vue js code in your blade file, as it will be compiled on the client side.. you can add a method to the td, and bind to vuejs..